# ford transit rear door won't close properly

Tags: ford

Hi I brought a van recently. I only found out out, the rear doors don't shut parallel to the floor when one of the doors was blown shut whilest I was taking out the bulkhead.

I can stick my entire hand inbetween the door and the floor.

I was wondering whats the most likely cause of this?

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CyxNn3wLsO8N-VhI6Uu-hKyrsuAxPUOG

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CyxNn3wLsO8N-VhI6Uu-hKyrsuAxPUOG

Comment: Do you have some images showing the issue?

Comment: It may look like I've not latched it properly but I tried pushing the door in. According to mot history, it's had problems where it wasn't able to be opened at all.

Comment: I can see it's off kilter here, but I cannot tell what part is what. I'm sorry to be asking, but do you have the year/make/model of the vehicle as well as some broader shots showing the complete door and it's relationship to the pillars, etc. These are great detail you have, but we need to see a broader picture as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got this resolved but mine has a similar issue, however it wasn't a mystery to me because I watched it happen.
My right rear door (driver's side, the first one to open - I believe LHD vans are reversed but could be mistaken, doesn't really matter) doesn't close properly. It will close and latch but as soon as I pull on the handle it pops open, and it requires some force to close properly.

The cause of this problem in my case was the door being caught by wind while it was open, forcing it to push past the check strap and towards the side of the van. I have 180 degree hinges, so this has caused the hinge mounts on the van side to bend outwards. It also broke the check strap which I have since replaced.

I have not resolved the hinge issue yet since it not as severe as yours, but will attempt to do so soon; what I will attempt is to remove the door and thread a sacrificial bolt into the hinge mount on the van side, and then push/pull/hammer it towards the centre of the van to reseat the hinges.

Also worth noting, though since it has been MOT tested and noted on there it may already have been attempted on yours, the hinges do have a small measure of lateral and height adjustment on the door side which may be enough to get your door to open and close more easily.